# distribution of sample variance or sample coefficient of variation under gamma parent distribution

Tags: variance, sample, gamma-distribution, coefficient-of-variation

I am looking for anything related to the distribution of the sample variance or sample coefficient of variation (or joint with sample mean or conditional on sample mean) when the parent distribution is Gamma. Any information of reference would be greatly appreciated.